# Move parent themes customization into child theme

Tags: wordpress

I have an ecommerce site's header and footer built using drag and drop builder. When I shift the parent theme to child theme, all of the customization of drag and drop are lost. What could be a way to load a child theme without losing the parent theme customization?

Comment: If you don't have footer.php in your child theme, it should use your parent themes footer etc.

Comment: @Stender: Its using the parent themes footer/header files. The problem is that the header and footer are built using customizer and require reconfiguration once the child theme loads.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Problem is each theme saves its data separately in a different row of the same table either it's parent or child. WordPress treats them as a single theme. So, you have to again re-create child theme. You can do it faster as you know what modifications were done.

For more information.

- [get the settings into the child theme](https://www.sktthemes.net/forums/topic/theme-options-lost-when-creating-a-child-theme/)
- [Child themes should inherit parent theme customizer settings on activation / switching](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/27177)
- [Child themes should inherit parent theme customizer settings on activation / switching](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-trac/2014-February/209454.html)

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thanks. They do have a patch for it in the [thread] you mentioned.(https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/27177/35997.patch) .

Comment: Can you share how can we convert this patch to a custom plugin?

Comment: @FahadUddin - Please follow this link to create [simple custom plugin](http://webcraft.tools/how-to-create-a-simple-wordpress-plugin/) in WordPress in place of code replace your patch code.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so from what I understand is that this problem is dependent on how the parent theme you start with has been programmed.  I happened to encounter this problem with the WP twentyseventeen theme, which I might have expected it to handle the theme_mods_ options better.

Anyway, one of the links listed by Sunil had a post written by Laura Kohan identified a couple of database entries that contianed all of the customizer options related to the child theme. In my case, I am using the twentyseventeen theme as the parent, and I was only able to identify one database entry that was pertinent to the situation and seemed to store relevant data about the child theme, and that was the **theme_mods_twentyseventeen_child** option in the wp_options table of the database. I noticed that the **theme_mods_twentyseventeen** option contained all the customizations from the parent in the form of a long array, so I simply decided to copy that array to the child's field. Of course, it would be smart to, save the child theme_mods_ option in a text file, or elsewhere before overwriting it with the parent data, but, for me, getting the customizations that I wanted was as simple as that...

For those people who don't know how to access the database, BEWARE!, changing data like this is not usually a good idea. You have to be very careful because often, some database entries will reference other entries, and it can get really messy. In fact this entry references custom_css_post_id, and possibly some others that you may want to consider carefully if you want keep the value from the child ID or use the one from the parent... But to point you in the right direction, most web hosting services will have PHPMyAdmin available for you in the cpanel, from there you can view your database, and from there find the table called wp_options, in which you'll find the relevant entries/options. And like Laura's situation, other themes may have some other extra entries to consider so be careful with that as well.

I think there might be a better way of directing WP to use a particular set of "mod" options in the child functions.php file, but so far I have not seen a good example of that. It would be nice to see some examples for: (1) referencing the parent mod options, (2) referencing the child specific mod options, and (3) copying the parent mods to the child mods. (another link by GreenShady in Sunil's post had some code that looked like it might do the copying, but I couldn't get it to work, perhaps someone else can provide a better example.)

Anyway, good luck...